# GoogleMaps JS can't load map anymore in China

Tags: google-maps-api-3

> In the app, we use Google Maps to provide services to users in different countries.

---

main code...

```
/// It works until February 4, 2020, but now it can't load the map correctly.
/// I haven't made any changes...
///
MapManager.loadGMapAPIScript = function(){

   var script = doc.createElement("script");
   script.id = "map_api_script";
   script.type = "text/javascript";
   script.src = "http://maps.google.cn/maps/api/js?sensor=false&v=3.40&key="my-googlemap-key-here"&callback=initialize_";
   script.defer = "true";
   script.async = "true";

   if(MapLanguage.language){

     script.src += "&language=" + MapLanguage.language;
   }

   doc.body.appendChild(script);
};
```

> ***Console error log: "net::ERR_ABORTED 503 (Service Unavailable)"***

- It seems that the “**maps.google.cn**” is no longer accessible?
- the **"maps.googleapis.com"** works, but it can't be accessed without VPN in China.

---

**Q: How can I continue to use GoogleMap-JS in China and other regions without VPN ?**

Comment: What doesn't work? What has changed from yesterday? What error(s) do you get in your javascript console? What **exact** API url are you using? Do you use a valid API key? etc. etc. etc.

Comment: Could you reopen the question for me? Thx~

Comment: Someone (you?) reported [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/148934417). You should report yours as well if that wasn't you.

Comment: Google answered: Google Maps Platform APIs will no longer be hosted from google.cn domain starting February 3, 2020. With this, all requests to load Google Maps Platform APIs from the google.cn domain will return an error.

Comment: @xomena Thank you very much. So... there's no better way for me than to change the map or use VPN ?

Comment: @MrUpsidown Yes, it's my report. Thx~

Comment: I don't think that's what they meant... But they could be a bit clearer about the issue and I am not sure if it was announced/explained anywhere. Doesn't it work if you call the googleapis domain without VPN?

Answer (score 5):

Google announced in November 2019 that maps.google.cn was going away on Feb 3, 2020. They told us to switch to using maps.googleapis.com with a region=CN query string parameter (other parameters were the same from what I recall).

But the new URI doesn't work. The JS file is blocked in China. I opened a support ticket yesterday and Google simply pointed me to the prohibited territory list last updated in May 2018. China is on the list which is very strange because maps.google.cn had worked for at least a couple of years. Google is being very cryptic in their response when I asked when this behavior was officially changed. I almost get the impression that Google maps was not ever supposed to work in China and the fact that it did was an accident.

Comment: No, it didn't work by accident otherwise why would they have created and open the API access on that `.cn` domain? Now if their answer to Chinese users is that they should switch to the `.com` domain, knowing that this domain is still blacklisted and inaccessible from China, that's really poor handling of a problem (Google is often quite good at that TBH). I would suppose this has impacted quite a lot of websites / developers in CN.

Comment: You might want to check the API documentation for [QQ maps](https://lbs.qq.com/webApi/javascriptV2/jsDoc/jsDocIndex). I would *really* do the move if I had a website / project intended for Chinese users (in China). And the API methods, parameters, etc. will look very very very familiar to anyone knowing Google Maps API v3 ;)

Comment: As of July 2020, this solution is working fine: https://dingyu.me/blog/google-maps-api-china